# Set password on backup files of cpanel

Tags: perl, passwords, backup, cpanel

I want to set password on `.tar.gz` file backups of [`Cpanel`](http://cpanel.com/) backup system.
The cpanel use a `perl` script for doing backup in `/scripts/cpbackup` file path.
So, I edit this file and find this function in here:

```
sub backupaccts {
    my $target      = shift;
    my $all_targets = shift;

    Cpanel::FileUtils::TouchFile::touchfile($target);

    #if another cpbackup starts just go bye bye

    if ( !( $CONF{'BACKUPFILES'} eq "no" ) ) {
        print "[cpbackup] Running dir & file backup with target : $target\n";
        if ( !-e "$target/files" ) {
            mkdir( "$target/files", 0700 );
        }
        if ( !-e "$target/dirs" ) {
            mkdir( "$target/dirs", 0700 );
        }
        chmod( 0700, "$target/files", "$target/dirs" );
        my ( $syncstatus, $syncmessage );
        foreach my $file (@FILES) {
            next if ( !-e $file );
            my $rawfile = $file;
            $rawfile =~ s/\//_/g;
            if ( $CONF{'BACKUPINC'} eq "yes" ) {
                ( $syncstatus, $syncmessage ) = Cpanel::SimpleSync::syncfile( $file, "$target/files/$rawfile", 0, 1 );
            }
            else {
                ( $syncstatus, $syncmessage ) = Cpanel::SimpleSync::syncfile( $file, "$target/files/$rawfile", 0, 1 );

                if ( $syncstatus != 0 ) {
                    if ( cpusystem( $gzip_bin, "-f", "$target/files/$rawfile" ) != 0 ) {
                        print STDERR "[cpbackup] Failed to compress file $target/files/$rawfile\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            if ( $syncstatus == 0 ) { print STDERR "[cpbackup] Failed to backup $file ($syncmessage)\n"; }
        }

        foreach my $dir (@DIRS) {
            next if ( !-e $dir );
            my $rawdir = $dir;
            $rawdir =~ s/\//_/g;

            my @EXCLUDES = (
                $dir eq '/var/cpanel'
                ? ( "--exclude=lastrun/*", "--exclude=bwusagecache/*", "--exclude=serviceauth/*", "--exclude=dnsrequests_db/*", "--exclude=configs.cache/*" )
                : ("--exclude=*/proc/*")
            );

            # Added exclude for /proc for chroot bind setups to prevent error messages
            if ( $CONF{'BACKUPINC'} eq "yes" ) {
                if ( cpusystem( $rsync_bin, $rsyncopts, @EXCLUDES, '--delete', "$dir/", "$target/dirs/$rawdir" ) != 0 ) {
                    print STDERR "[cpbackup] Failed to perform incremental backup of $dir/ to $target/dirs/$rawdir\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                if ( cpusystem( $tar_bin, '--use-compress-program=/usr/local/cpanel/bin/gzip-wrapper', '--create', '--preserve-permissions', '--file', "$target/dirs/$rawdir.tar.gz", @EXCLUDES, $dir ) == 0 ) {
                    chmod( 0600, "$target/dirs/$rawdir.tar.gz" );
                }
                else {
                    print STDERR "[cpbackup] Failed to perform full backup of $dir/ to $target/dirs/$rawdir.tar.gz\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    print "[cpbackup] Running account backup with target : $target\n";

    #BACKUPLOGS no
    #MYSQLBACKUP accounts
    #BACKUPBWDATA yes
    $ENV{'pkgacct-logs'} = ( $CONF{'BACKUPLOGS'} eq "yes" ? 'yes' : 'no' );
    $ENV{'pkgacct-mysql'}  = ( ( $CONF{'MYSQLBACKUP'} eq "dir" || $CONF{'MYSQLBACKUP'} eq "no" ) ? 'no' : 'yes' );
    $ENV{'pkgacct-psql'}   = ( $CONF{'PSQLBACKUP'} eq "no"                                       ? 'no' : 'yes' );
    $ENV{'pkgacct-bwdata'} = ( $CONF{'BACKUPBWDATA'} eq "no"                                     ? 'no' : 'yes' );

    my %user_error_map = ();
    if ( $CONF{'BACKUPACCTS'} ne 'no' ) {

        # we need to be sure that all accounts are converted to the new backup system
        #     user config need to have the LEGACY_BACKUP entry
        #    this can be missing when importing an account prior 11.36
        #    or if an error happen during the upgrade process
        Install::LegacyBackups->new()->perform();

        Cpanel::PwCache::init_passwdless_pwcache();

        my @cpusers = Cpanel::Config::Users::getcpusers();
        foreach my $user ( sort @cpusers ) {
            my $user_conf = Cpanel::Config::LoadCpUserFile::load($user);
            $user_conf->{'LEGACY_BACKUP'} = 0 if !exists $user_conf->{'LEGACY_BACKUP'};
            next if !$user_conf->{'LEGACY_BACKUP'};

            if ( $CONF{'BACKUPINC'} eq 'yes' ) {
                my $last_update_time = time();
                utime( $last_update_time, $last_update_time, "$target/$user" );
            }
            if ( cpusystem( $pkgacct, ( $CONF{'COMPRESSACCTS'} eq 'no' ? '--nocompress' : () ), ( $CONF{'BACKUPINC'} eq "yes" ? '--incremental' : () ), $user, $target, 'backup' ) != 0 ) {
                print STDERR "[cpbackup] Failed to back up account $user\n";
                $user_error_map{$user}{'account'} = {
                    'error_message' => ( $LAST_CPUSYSTEM_ERROR || 'Failed to backup account' )    # FIXME: This is a hack to avoid refactoring cpusystem
                };
            }
            else {
                if ( $CONF{'BACKUPTYPE'} eq 'ftp' ) {
                    my $target_file = ( $CONF{'COMPRESSACCTS'} eq 'no' ? "$user.tar" : "$user.tar.gz" );
                    foreach my $remote_target (@$all_targets) {                                   # If we are going to update multiple targets we send the file multiple times
                                                                                                  # previously we would build the backup once for every target.  Now we just upload it once
                                                                                                  # instead as we know all the targets before we get here now
                        my %ftp_error_info = ftpsend( $remote_target, $target . '/' . $target_file, $target_file );
                        $user_error_map{$user}{'transport'}{$remote_target} = \%ftp_error_info if keys %ftp_error_info;
                    }
                    unlink( $target . '/' . $target_file );
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return \%user_error_map;
}
```

As you can see, this line doing create `.tar.gz` file for archived backup:

```
cpusystem( $tar_bin, '--use-compress-program=/usr/local/cpanel/bin/gzip-wrapper', '--create', '--preserve-permissions', '--file', "$target/dirs/$rawdir.tar.gz", @EXCLUDES, $dir )
```

I know about how using `zip`, `gpg`, `crypt`,... But I don't know that how can I use it in this function and append that.

What's your idea for doing this work? and I don't know perl programming so please provide a sample code for me if you can.

Comment: You could add your own wrapper around this gzip-wrapper that gpg the resulting .tar.gz into a .tar.gz.encrypted, wiping/erasing the .tar.gz afterwards

Comment: @flaviodesousa Do you can provide a code with edit above code?

Answer (score 0):

> I know about how using zip, gpg, crypt,... But I don't know that how can I use it in this function and append that.

I don't think you should modify the Cpanel software, and tar has no password support. So you should use either `gpg` or `crypt` to encrypt the .tar.gz after it has been created, deleting the original file in the process